# Duplicate Values in Drop downs

Tags: php

There is a drop down in my update form , so when i select a row to update then that value is automatically filled in the drop down . So, what i want is , if Employee is **present** then **only absent should be shown in the drop down** and **vice versa.**   **Here is the Code Snippet:**

```
<td>
  <select name="Status" id="Status" class='form-control' required autofocus>
    <?php
    if (isset($_SESSION["state"])) {
      foreach ($_SESSION['state'] as $states) {
        echo "<option value='$states'>$states</option>";
      }
    }
    ?>
    <option value="Present"<?= $state == "Present" ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>> Present </option>
    <option value="Absent"<?= $state == "Absent" ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>> Absent </option>
  </select>
</td>
```

So,if **Present** comes in Session value , then based on that only **absent** should be shown in the dropdown.

Comment: So wrap them both in appropriate `if` blocks then ... where is the actual problem with that?

Comment: please show me how ?

Comment: No, please describe what about this you are having trouble with. Show us your attempt.

Comment: what is `$state`? is it defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you want to display one of these options so use if statement to select one of them according to the condition if it is present so display this one and if it is absent so display that one

```
<?php
if($state=="Present"){
?>
<option value="Present" selected="selected"> Present     </option>
<?php
}
else{
?>
 <option value="Absent" selected="selected"> Absent   </option>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a for Loop

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION["state"])) {
if($_SESSION['state']=="Present"){
echo "<option value='Absent' selected='selected'>Absent</option>";
}
else
{
echo "<option value='Present' selected='selected'>Present</option>";
}
?>
</select>
</td>    
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: giving Errror  :    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in D:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\AttendanceUpdateForm.php on line 105

Comment: sort out the }'s and you'll get your result.

Comment: check it out now

Comment: error is solved but , if state is present , then absent is not shown in dropdown

Comment: it will how now , test the updated code. If the solution is working do mark this answer as the correct answer to your problem. :)

Comment: not showing, also, if i select the employee who is absent it still shows Present in the drop down.

Comment: Please help Buudy